# How to call preferredVideoStabilizationMode in GPUImage3?

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

I'm in the process of rebuilding an iOS app from ObjC + GPUImage to Swift + GPUImage3 (and a rank amateur coder!).

I previously used:

```
m_videoCamera.videoCaptureConnection.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeOff;
```

to set the stabilisation mode, but in GPUImage3 there seem to be no capture connections available. Can anyone suggest a way to access the capture connections to set `preferredVideoStabilizationMode`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it wasn't so difficult, by repurposing some of the code from within GPUImage3 Camera input I got it to work. Now there may be some obvious problem with this but it seems to be working so far

```
let device = videoCamera

if ((device?.inputCamera.activeFormat.isVideoStabilizationModeSupported(AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.standard))!){
        var captureConnection: AVCaptureConnection!
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            for connection in (device?.captureSession.connections)! {
                for port in connection.inputPorts {
                    if port.mediaType == AVMediaType.video {
                        captureConnection = connection
                        captureConnection.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = .standard
                        print("capture connection from within startStabilization is \(String(describing: captureConnection))")
                        print("preferred video stab mode set to on")
                        let currentStabMode = captureConnection.activeVideoStabilizationMode.rawValue
                        print("active stabilization mode from startStabilization is \(currentStabMode)")
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // put in warning pop up if stabilization not available
            print("startStabilization failed")
        }
}
```